# Import csv files from folders inside zip folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip, python-zipfile

I have zip folder namely zip_file.zip, and thousands of folders are inside of it. There are also thousands of .csv files inside these folders and I want to import all csv files and concat them. I tried the solution that I found in Stackoverflow but it doesn't work. Could you please help?

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = zipfile.ZipFile('/zip_file.zip')
all_files = all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: can you mention the error or result that shows why it's not working? probably it's because `glob` and `pandas` have some problems working on unextracted zip files. do you mind temporarily extracting your zip file?

Comment: When I run the code block above, nothing happens... I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `dask` which will use [`fsspec`](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) under the hood for complex read situations:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_csv

# this line will create a pandas dataframe
df = read_csv('zip://*.csv::zip_file.zip').compute()
```

Note that `.compute` call assumes that the data fits into memory. If this is not the case, you will need to think further about how you want the data to be processed.

Also, the above assumes that you have dask installed, if not, install it in the terminal/shell via pip (or conda):

```bash
pip install dask
```