# Dask (fsspec) reading and concatenating csv files of the same name from multiple zip files

Tags: python, dask, fsspec

I have multiple zip files, each of which contain csv files of the same name e.g.

- foo1.zip contains a.csv, b.csv, c.csv
- foo2.zip contains a.csv, b.csv, c.csv
- foo3.zip contains a.csv, b.csv, c.csv etc..

I am looking to read each csv file of a given name from each zip file and concatenate them. So all the a files would be concatenated, all the b files concatenated and so on. (a, b, c will later be merged - I am using Dask as the final file won't fit in memory).

I have tried using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72585287/import-csv-files-from-folders-inside-zip-folder) but with swapping the wildcard from the file name to the zip file:

```
dfa = dd.read_csv('zip://a.csv::foo*.zip' ,delimiter=";", header=0,index_col=False)
result = dfa.compute()
print(result)
```

However this is only loading the a.csv file from the first zip. I have also tried:

```
dfa = dd.read_csv("foo*.zip::a.csv",delimiter=";", header=0,index_col=False)
```

but that seems to read every csv, regardless of the name.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Expecting `dfa = dd.read_csv('zip://a.csv::foo*.zip' ,delimiter=";", header=0,index_col=False)` to open and concatenate all 'a.csv' files from all zip files matching foo*.zip.

Result: Only the first a.csv file was returned.

Comment: read_csv can also take a list of file path as an argument, did you try it? Something like: read_csv(['zip://a.csv:foo1.zip', 'zip://a.csv:foo2.zip', ...])

Comment: I tried that but it seems to just be reading the first 'a.csv' file every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fsspec only supports performing the glob on the inner-most filesystem (within a ZIP in this case) rather than over multiple possible filesystems.

Furthermore, a single call to read_csv will always produce just one filesystem, so both of your paths are being interpreted in the context of just one zip file, as you have noticed. This was a design decision in early dask, to be able to tokenise tasks on the basis of the one filesystem in play.

To do the task, you will need to go manual:

```
dfs = [dd.read_csv(fn, ...) for fn in ("zip://a.csv::foo1.zip", "zip://a.csv::fo2.zip")]
ddf = dd.concat(dfs)
result = ddf.compute()
```